# pydantic schema to postgres db

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pydantic

I am trying to insert a pydantic schema (as json) to a postgres database using sqlalchemy. As you can see below I have defined a `JSONB` field to host the schema.

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, JSON
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSONB
from enum import Enum
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

import jsonref

Base = declarative_base()

class Values(Enum):
    one = 'one'
    two = 'two'

class Mdl(BaseModel):
    par: Enum = Field(
        title='trial',
        description='trial descr'
    )

class SqlTest(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'sql_test'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    param = Column(JSONB)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://user:password@localhost/mydb')

    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    row = SqlTest(id=1, param=Mdl.schema())
    row2 = SqlTest(id=1, param=jsonref.loads(Mdl.schema_json()))

    with Session(engine) as session:
        session.add(row)
        session.add(row2)
        session.commit()
```

However, when I insert the schema extracted via `Mdl.schema()` everything works as expected while when I extract the schema via `jsonref.loads(Mdl.schema_json()))`
I get the error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (builtins.TypeError) Object of type dict is not JSON serializable
```

How to fix this error? Apparently, both `row` and `row2` are `dict` types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution: if the schema is extracted via `jsonref`it needs to be converted to `str` before inserting to postgres:

```
row2 = SqlTest(id=1, param=str(jsonref.loads(Mdl.schema_json())))

with Session(engine) as session:
    session.add(row2)
    session.commit()
```